# Create Auto Responder using Powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I want to use a Powershell script in which I can configure the user's Auto Responder Out Of Office mail.
The script should be able to take inputs such as username, duration, and message.
I am new to Powershell and so far I am able to get the MailBox values for the user.

Comment: Hi!  You should edit your post and share the code you have already written.  Then give more info to us.  If you have access to Exchange, you can set the out of office message easily using PowerShell.  If you want to set it through controlling outlook on a user's computer...it's messier.

Comment: As for the    [I am new to Powershell]   that's fine, but SO has rules. s[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -  [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). To do what you are after, you not only need to know PowerShell, you need to know Outlook Programming model (COM/DOM) ir order to open and work with Outlook. See Youtube vids on it.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I think I just wanted a readymade script to set Auto Responder. But thank you anyway, I'll check some videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below cmdlet to configure Out of office mail.

```html
Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -Identity tony -AutoReplyState Scheduled -StartTime "7/10/2018 08:00:00" -EndTime "7/15/2018 17:00:00" -InternalMessage "Internal auto-reply message." -ExternalMessage "External auto-reply message."
```

Comment: appreciate your help!!